# How can I improve "Total Blocking Time" using NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, page-load-time

I have an app created with NextJs, the problem that it loads very slow and the lighthouse scores are very bad aswell. [Lighthouse Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUjfQ.png)

Could someone please guide me and give me some actionable steps? Iam a noob when it comes to optimization.

Comment: If your app is online, perhaps you could use [GT Metrix](https://gtmetrix.com/). It will give you a cleaner and more readable (IMO, of course) list of things you should fix.

Comment: That turned out to be quite helpful, thank you for your recommendation.